# Setting of an array or array list of object

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm fairly new to coding so just wondering if someone can point me in the right direction. I'm looking to set up a Library class containing an array or array list of Book objects that carry out appropriate functions such as adding a Book, editing a Books details, deleting a Book, returning a Book and loaning a Book.

So far I have created the following Book class

```
//Instance variables
private int BookID;
private String Title;
private String Author;
private boolean On_Loan;
private int Number_of_Loans;

//Constructor
public Book(int BookID, String Title, String Author, boolean On_Loan, int Number_of_Loans){
    this.BookID = BookID;
    this.Title = Title;
    this.Author = Author;
    this.On_Loan = On_Loan;
    this.Number_of_Loans = Number_of_Loans;

}

//Mutator methods
public void setBookID(int BookID){
    this.BookID = BookID;
}
public void setTitle(String Title){
    this.Title = Title;
}
public void setAuthor(String Author){
    this.Author = Author;
}
public void setOn_Loan(boolean On_Loan){
    this.On_Loan = On_Loan;
}
public void setNumber_of_Loans(int Number_of_Loans){
    this.Number_of_Loans = Number_of_Loans;
}

//Accessor methods
public int getBookID(){
    return BookID;
}
public String getTitle(){
    return Title;
}
public String getAuthor(){
    return Author;
}
public boolean getOn_Loan(){
    return On_Loan;
}
public int getNumber_of_Loans(){
    return Number_of_Loans;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you know how to write a class in java?

Comment: So far I have a book class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `ArrayList<Book>` object! To create one:

```
ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<> ();
```

To add an item to it,

```
books.add (yourBookObjectToBeAdded);
```

To change the books' properties, you need to get the book first,

```
books.get(theIndexOfTheBook);
```

It is recommended to store the book in a variable:

```
Book myBook = books.get(theIndexOfTheBook);
```

And then you can use one of the mutators (setters),

```
myBook.setOn_Loan (true);
```

Advantages:

- unlike arrays, `ArrayList` is dynamic in size.
- It is generic, you don't need to cast stuff.

And that is basically a guide to using array lists. Now you want to make a class that do all this stuff. So it must contain an `ArrayList<Book>`:

```
public class Library {
    private ArrayList<Book> books
    public Library () {
       books = new ArrayList<> ();
    }

    public ArrayList<Book> getBooks () {
        return books;
    }
}
```

Then the user can get the `books` and do operations on the array list.

Alternatively, you can make it more abstract. You can add `borrowBook`, `returnBook`, `editBook` and other methods to the class. For example, the `borrowBook` method would be like this:

```
public void borrowBook (int bookIndex) {
    Book book = books.get(bookIndex);
    book.setOn_Loan (true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

first, you will have to create the Book object

then you can create an array of Book objects like this

```
Book[] books = new Book[10]; //fixed list of size 10
Book b1 = new Book(); // create a book object
books[0] = b1; // assign it to be the first array element
```

or an arraylist list like this

```
ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>(); //initial empty list, no fixed size
Book b1 = new Book(); // create a book object
books.add(b1); // append it to the list
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I have created the Book object

Answer (score 0):

If their is a variable number of books, using an ArrayList will be a good choice, as you can add more books on the fly, unlike an array, where you have to fix the size.

To create an ArrayList of Book objects, use: `ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();`

To add a book to the list: `books.add(new Book());`

To perform a command on a book (i.e. edit the details), you need to know the index of the book, or you could go through all of them. You can do this using the .get(index) command, for example:

```
books.get(index).doSomething();
```

You can read more about ArrayLists and all of their methods [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), and a simple tutorial could be found [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/array_lists.html).